# Help me to ask an question I have found source called "How a Mother Would Tell the Buddha’s Birth Story
"

Tags: discussion

I've found this source [How a Mother Would Tell the Buddha’s Birth Story](https://tricycle.org/trikedaily/buddhas-birth/amp/).

I want to share this with all of you my Buddhist friends.

So ask a question relates to this source and use the source to answer it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Not really a story worthy to share...

> ...To me, this sounds like the version of the myth told by a man who has never given birth. The male baby is the hero of the story, not the mother who gave him life from her body. The woman is the passive vessel for a man’s awakening journey, not a heroine embarked on her own grueling quest to become fully alive.

What a loose would be a giver of generosities conceit. Be sure that most blessed Queen Maya was not that foolish like those many Gender-confused and Yoni-worshipping this days, Upasaka Swapnil.

Comment: Thanks a lot Bhante.  You've always been there to tell me which one is wrong or right.

Comment: Only one with Saddha is able to receive the goodness derived form the Buddha, Upasaka Swapnil. Gratitude and long beneficial help is a sign of the Noble ones: "Seven days later Māyā died and was reborn as a male in the Tusita world, under the name of Māyādevaputta (Thag.vss.533f.; ThagA.i.502).

The Buddha visited Tāvatimsa immediately after the performance of the Twin Miracle... [Mahāmāyā](http://www.palikanon.com/english/pali_names/maha/mahamaayaa.htm)

Comment: Thanks a lot Bhante to tell me Dhamma.  May Buddha bless you 